# Why is val() returning 'dummy text' when I get the value from an empty textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7

Testing in IE7 with jQuery.

When I call `$("textarea").val()` on an empty textarea element, it returns `dummy text`.

I have never seen this before.  Any insight would be recommended.

Comment: We're gonna need some code I'm afraid. I don't think this is part of jQuery ;)

Comment: Maybe a dummy put the text there?

Comment: Does it literally return "dummy text" or something like lorem ipsum? Either way it sounds like something else is the cause.

Comment: sounds like you have a 'placeholder' attribute in there.

Comment: Are you using some kind of placeholder script?

Answer (score 1):

here is a fiddle using all your information to reconstruct your problem

http://jsfiddle.net/sT3Wh/

your problem isnt appearing in any browser.

solutions:

- feed us with more details
- search your scripts for this strange output
- try to reconstruct it yourself and maybe youll find the error yourself

Comment: I just solved my problem.  I have to wait 8 hours before answering my own question though.